# String literals and J2EE Bad Practices: Non-Serializable Object Stored in Session

Tags: java, string, jakarta-ee, literals, fortify

Fortify is flagging a line similar to this

```
session.setAttribute("foo", "bar")
```

https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.structural.java.j2ee_bad_practices_non_serializable_object_stored_in_session

There is a similar question on here for .NET where the answer was that it is a "false positive" because the documentation demands the values must implement ISerializable, which String does not.  But in the J2EE version of the documentation it must only implement Serializable.  Which String does.

Is the problem that it is a String literal?  Would the following eliminate the Fortify message?

```
session.setAttribute("foo", new String("bar"))
```

**UPDATE**
I have three Fortify warnings and they are all String literals.
It doesn't seem to mind String properties, e.g. the following passes:

```
session.setAttribute("foo", myObject.myString)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in Fortify. For a very basic feature. Or your "line similar to this" is not really similar. Please show more representative code.

Comment: @Thilo It is very similar.  I just replaced the two literals to protect my company's identity.  Also there are 3 separate Fortify examples and in all three cases the value being put in the session is a String literal.  It doesn't complain about String properties, e.g. myObject.myString passes.

Comment: Well, if they are both String literals, then it is a bug in Fortify. Maybe changing it to add indirection via moving them into `private static final String` fields gets it unstuck.

Comment: And to be specific, there is exactly no difference between `"string literal"`  and `new String("string literal")` from this point of view, and any software, or person, which claims there is doesn't know what it's talking about.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the problem that it is a `String` literal?

No. Both `"bar"` and `new String("bar")` are `String` objects and both are serialisable since their class implements `java.io.Serializable`.

> Would the following eliminate the Fortify message?

You tell me. If neither or only one of these works, it's a Fortify issue, not yours.

Maybe it's warning about a different `String` literal problem, like using literals instead of constants.

Comment: I'm not sure when the next Fortify run will be.  As an experiment I shall try both, plus the static final from @Thilo and see which if any quietens it down.

Comment: @hobbes_child ok, let me know when you are done. If it doesn't resolve the warning, you can report a bug.